# Trying to create a math game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a revised/edited code down below for a simple math game. You enter an amount that you want to solve and then you solve it!

The problem I am having now is that at the very end, it only displays the score.

I am trying to have it not only display the score, but the amount of questions that you entered to solve. Therefore it is more of a "You got" score "out of " questions entered correct. Below is the code and the link to the Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/justinw001/Mttw6/12/

```
$(function () {
    var score = 0;
    var questions = [];
    $('#gen').click(function () {
        score = 0;
        questions = [];
        var questionAmount = parseInt($('#inputElement').val(), 10);
        for (var i = 0; i < questionAmount; i++) {
            var q = {
                x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 13),
                y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)
            };
            questions.push(q);
        }
        nextQuest(questions.pop());
    });
    $('#sub').click(function () {
        var ans, x, y;
        if (questions.length >= 0) {
            ans = parseInt($('#answer').val(), 10);
            x = parseInt($('#input1').text(), 10);
            y = parseInt($('#input2').text(), 10);
            if (ans === x * y) {
                score++;
            }
            nextQuest(questions.pop());
        }
    });
    var nextQuest = function (q) {
        if (q) {
            $('#input1').text(q.x);
            $('#input2').text(q.y);
            $('#answer').val('');
            $('#inputElement').val(questions.length);
        } else {
            $('#input1, #input2').text('');
            $('#answer, #inputElement').val('');
            alert(score);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: A jsFiddle would help here.

Comment: There is a Fiddle at the top below the question I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare questionAmount outside the function

```
$(function () {
    var score = 0;
    var questions = [];
    var questionAmount=0; //here
    $('#gen').click(function () {
        score = 0;
        questions = [];
        questionAmount = parseInt($('#inputElement').val(), 10);
```

then when you alert do this

```
 alert(score+" out of "+questionAmount + " correct");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mttw6/14/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mttw6/16/) is a working fiddle of what you want. Just add a `var numberOfQs;` then set that to the `questionAmount` and alert it with the score.